# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on Windows

Tags: ros, roslib, windows, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to run a very thin client on windows. It is supposed to be only a message sender. I found this link on ROS web site. http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Windows

It asks me to install roslib and rospy on my windows client. The question is how it is possible. Is there any binary file that I install it on my windows, or I have to install them from their source codes? They have dependencies to other packages. What should I do with them?

Bests,
Shams

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32607/ros-on-windows/) by [Shams](https://answers.ros.org/users/2251/shams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-25**:
Now that Fuerte is released, this should be easier, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Update

It is possible to install and use ROS Lunar on Windows 10 thanks to WSL:
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

This is the best way to use ROS on Windows right now, though it is not perfect.

---

Please see the more recent Fuerte-era ROS Windows instructions.  ROS on Windows is a work in progress, and you should always use the most recent release.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Windows

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-07**:
I believe it's important to recognise that ROSonWSL is not the same as having a native Win32/64 ROS. WSL does not have the same level of access to Windows resources, so 'driver' components wanting to access hw (usb, gpus for gpgpu fi) will not work (easily).